# naive Lomuto's Partition in Quicksort can handle duplicates?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I code up Quicksort algorithm with Hoare and Lomuto partition (the ones written in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort)

Hoare's partition can't handle duplicates, but Lomuto's partition can. 
Is that true ? just ~10 lines of code, Lomuto's partition can handle every case, although it's slower than Hoare's one. If that's not true, give me an example.

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/11458/quicksort-partitioning-hoare-vs-lomuto

Comment: Due to memory cache, swaps don't cost much, as two (or one) cache lines are already loaded for the two elements from prior compares. [Hoare partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Hoare_partition_scheme) becomes faster as the number of duplicates increases, while [Lomuto partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Lomuto_partition_scheme) becomes slower as the number of duplicates increases.